# I get "Uploaded Successfully" but nothing shows in my database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, prisma

I'm trying to upload my excel file into my database using `NodeJs/Express+Prisma` and `mysql` for backend, I'm running the MySQL locally. I'm having a hard which part I'm wrong because I don't see any messages.

This is what I get when I POST it.

[image]

But nothing adds in my Database.

This is my uploadFile.js

```
import express from "express";
import fileUpload from "express-fileupload";
import XLSX from "xlsx";
import fs from "fs";

const router = express.Router();

const uploadOpts = {
  useTempFiles: true,
  tempFileDir: "/tmp/",
};

router.post("/", fileUpload(uploadOpts), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { excel } = req.files;
    if (
      excel.mimetype !==
      "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    ) {
      fs.unlinkSync(excel.tempFilePath);
      return res.status(400).json({ msg: "File is invalid!" });
    }

    const workbook = XLSX.readFile(excel.tempFilePath);
    const sheetName = workbook.SheetNames[0];
    const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);

    const successData = [];
    const failureData = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      const { email, studentId, firstName, lastName, department } = data[i];

      try {
        const addUser = await db.user.create({
          data: {
            email,
            studentId,
            firstName,
            lastName,
            department,
          },
        });
        successData.push(addUser);
      } catch (error) {
        failureData.push({ ...data[i], error: error.message });
      }
    }
    fs.unlinkSync(excel.tempFilePath); // Delete temporary file after processing
    return res.json({ msg: "Uploaded Successfully" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(500).json({ msg: "Internal Server Error" });
  }
});

export default router;
```

My Prisma.Schema

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id         Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  email      String @unique
  studentId  String @unique
  firstName  String
  lastName   String
  department String

  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}
```

new_sample.xlsx
[image]

Comment: you have `successData` and `failureData` arrays ... which you populate ... but never check ... how do you know that `db.user.create` is ever successful? or that `data.length` is > 0?